# elasticsearch hadoop integration- java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, hive

I downloaded `elasticsearch2.1.2` JAR and followed the guide to configure it in `Hadoop`(v5.4.4). Everything looks ok but I am getting **'CAST' error** while reading from the elasticsearch source. Below is the error message-

> Failed with exception java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.mr.WritableArrayWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Below is the table created in hive-
    CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE Log_Event_ICS_ES(
    product_version string,
    agent_host string,
    product_name string,
    temp_time_stamp bigint,
    log_message string,
    org_id string,
    log_datetime timestamp,
    message string,
    log_source_provider string,
    log_source_name string,
    log_message_for_trending string,
    index_only_message string,
    log_level string,
    code_source string,
    log_type string,
    full_message string,
    session_log_operation string,
    source_received_time timestamp
    )
    STORED BY 'org.elasticsearch.hadoop.hive.EsStorageHandler'
    TBLPROPERTIES('es.resource' = 'log_event_2015-05-11/log_event',
    'es.nodes' = '',
    'es.port' = ''
    )

```
Select query- select * from log_event_ics_es
```

Any idea?

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include relevant queries? Almost certainly something doesn't match up, but there's no way of working it out without the queries.

Comment: edited to include the query in hive to read elasticsearch index